# How should I make a future-proof table for different LEGO brick sizes?

Tags: duplo

I'm trying to decide on a table or base for my 3 year old - one she can grow with.  She is using Duplo bricks currently but also already has some regular LEGO bricks.  What kind of base will work with both so I don't have to have separate tables or bases?  Any help appreciated!!